Getting File Wasn't Available On Site . When Iam Generating and Downloading Excel File In Blazor Wasm
I', Using Blazor Wasm 7.0.14 . I Wrote a Code That Will Generate and Download an Excel File From Data In The DataGrid When I Click On a Button .
The Problem Is When I Click On The Button Iam Getting "Couldn't Download The File , File Wasn't Available On Site "
**Screen Code **
<style>
    .my-header-class .mud-table-cell {
        background-color: #92a8d1;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
</style>


 
<MudDataGrid Items="@HorecaInformations" Filterable="true" Virtualize="true" Striped="true" FixedHeader="true" Height="400px"
             QuickFilter="@_quickFilter" ColumnResizeMode="ResizeMode.None" Bordered="false" Outlined="true" SortMode="SortMode.Single" FilterMode="DataGridFilterMode.Simple" >

    <ToolBarContent>
        
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="_searchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true"
                      AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
        <button @onclick="ExportToExcel">
            Download
        </button>
        <a id="exportCsv" class="btn" href="https://localhost:7281/exports/horeca.xlsx" download="horeca.xlsx"
           role="button" target="=_top">Export to Excel</a>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <Columns>
        <HierarchyColumn T="GetHorecaInformationsViewModel"  />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Id" Title="Id"  Hidden="true"/>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" Title="Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Governorate" Title="Governorate" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.OwnerName" Title="Owner Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.OwnerPhone" Title="Owner Phone" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.PurcasingManagerName" Title="Purchase Manager Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.PurchasingManagerPhone" Title="Purchase Manager Phone" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Concept" Title="Concept" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.CreatedBy" Title="Created By" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.CreatedDate" Title="Created Date" Hideable="true"/>
        <TemplateColumn CellClass="d-flex justify-end" Filterable="false">
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudStack Row>
                    <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Rounded.RemoveRedEye" Color="Color.Primary" @onclick="() => ShowDetails(context.Item)" />
                    <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Rounded.Delete" Color="Color.Error" @onclick="() => OnShowButtonClicked(context.Item)" />
                    <a href="@context.Item.Location" target="_blank" class="btn">
                        <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Rounded.LocationOn" Color="Color.Surface"/>
                    </a>
                </MudStack>
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    <ChildRowContent>
        <MudCard>
            <MudCardHeader>
                <CardHeaderContent>
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">@context.Item.Name</MudText>
                    </CardHeaderContent>
                </MudCardHeader>
                <MudCardContent>
                    <MudDataGrid Items="@context.Item.getHorecaStatictsInformationViewModels" Filterable="false" Virtualize="true" Striped="true" Height="300px">
                        <Columns>
                            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Rating" Title="Rating" />
                            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.TablesCount" Title="Tables Count" />
                            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ChairsCount" Title="Chairs Count" />
                            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.IsHePasabahceBuyer" Title="Is Pasabahce Buyer" />
                            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.PasabahcePercentage" Title="Pasabahce Percentage" />
                            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.IsHeBonnaBuyer" Title="Is Bonna Buyer" />
                            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.BonnaPercentage" Title="Bonna Percentage" />
                            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.IsHeNudeBuyer" Title="Is Nude Buyer" />
                            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.NudePercentage" Title="Nude Percentage" />
                        </Columns>
                    </MudDataGrid>
                </MudCardContent>
            </MudCard>
        </ChildRowContent>
</MudDataGrid>
    

<MudMessageBox @ref="mbox" Title="Warning" CancelText="Cancel">
    <MessageContent>
        Deleting can <b>not</b> be undone!
    </MessageContent>
    <YesButton>
        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Error" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.DeleteForever" @onclick="()=>RemoveHoreca()">Delete!</MudButton>
    </YesButton>
</MudMessageBox>

@code {
    private Guid selectedItemsId;
    private List<GetHorecaInformationsViewModel> HorecaInformations = new List<GetHorecaInformationsViewModel>();
    private string _searchString;
    MudMessageBox mbox { get; set; }
    string state = "Message box hasn't been opened yet";


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        HorecaInformations = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<GetHorecaInformationsViewModel>>("api/horeca");
    }

    private Func<GetHorecaInformationsViewModel, bool> _quickFilter => x =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_searchString))
            return true;

        if (x.Governorate.Contains(_searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        if (x.Name.Contains(_searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        if ($"{x.Name} {x.OwnerName} {x.OwnerPhone} {x.PurcasingManagerName} {x.PurchasingManagerPhone} {x.Governorate}".Contains(_searchString))
            return true;

        return false;
    };

    private void ShowDetails(GetHorecaInformationsViewModel row)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/horeca-details/{row.Id.ToString()}");
    }

    private async void RemoveHoreca()
    {
        var result = await httpClient.DeleteAsync($"api/horeca/{selectedItemsId}");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    private async void OnShowButtonClicked(GetHorecaInformationsViewModel row)
    {
        selectedItemsId = row.Id;
        bool? result = await mbox.Show();
    }

    private byte[] ProductsToBytes()
    {
        using var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Governorate"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OwnerName"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OwnerPhone"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PurcasingManagerName"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PurchasingManagerPhone"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Concept"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CreatedBy"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rating"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TablesCount"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ChairsCount"));
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CreatedDate"));

        HorecaInformations.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var newRow = datatable.NewRow();
            newRow["Name"] = x.Name;
            newRow["Governorate"] = x.Governorate;
            newRow["OwnerName"] = x.OwnerName;
            newRow["OwnerPhone"] = x.OwnerPhone;
            newRow["PurcasingManagerName"] = x.PurcasingManagerName;
            newRow["PurchasingManagerPhone"] = x.PurchasingManagerPhone;
            newRow["Concept"] = x.Concept;
            newRow["CreatedBy"] = x.CreatedBy;
            newRow["Rating"] = x.getHorecaStatictsInformationViewModels.FirstOrDefault().Rating;
            newRow["TablesCount"] = x.getHorecaStatictsInformationViewModels.FirstOrDefault().TablesCount;
            newRow["ChairsCount"] = x.getHorecaStatictsInformationViewModels.FirstOrDefault().ChairsCount;
            newRow["CreatedDate"] = x.getHorecaStatictsInformationViewModels.FirstOrDefault().CreatedDate;
            datatable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        });

        var workSheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(datatable,"HorecaData");
        using var memorystream = new MemoryStream();
        workbook.SaveAs(memorystream);
        return memorystream.ToArray();
    }

    private void SaveSpreadSheetBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        string rootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "exports");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath); // Ensure the directory exists
        string filePath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "horeca.xlsx");
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
    }

    public async Task ExportToExcel() 
    {
        var spreadsheetBytes = ProductsToBytes();
        SaveSpreadSheetBytes(spreadsheetBytes);
        await DownloadFileFromURL();
    }

    private async Task DownloadFileFromURL()
    {
        var fileName = "horeca.xlsx";
        var fileURL = "https://localhost:7281/exports/horeca.xlsx";
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerFileDownload", fileName, fileURL);
    }

}

**Script in index.html File **
    <script>
        window.triggerFileDownload = (fileName, url) => {
            const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
            anchorElement.href = url;
            anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
            anchorElement.click();
            anchorElement.remove();
        }
    </script>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I've used this quite a bit, this library handles a lot of different scenarios: https://github.com/arivera12/BlazorDownloadFile

I'm guessing the file is malformed in some way.  Maybe something isn't escaped correctly or maybe a value isn't being handled in a null-safe way.  Debug by simplifying the generated file to basic elements and then add parts back in one at a time until you see the problem.
I've found that if there is a button on the webpage, right click on that button and choose "Open link in new tab" - this might show you the real error message if the server is configured in that way.
In the past, Chrome would just download a weird file for you if it couldn't render out a webpage or file. Now it gives this rather vague "file wasn't available on site" error instead of just downloading malformed files now, it seems.
